# How can I identify duplicate application manifest certificates

Tags: c#, powershell, azure, azure-active-directory

I have successfully:

1. Created an Azure App Service
2. Registered it with AAD
3. Added a certificate to the application manifest using New-AzureADApplicationKeyCredential.
4. The customKeyIdentifier is set as follows: 
   `[Convert]::ToBase64String($global:CertificateInfo.Certificate.GetCertHash())` ;
5. Accessed the App Service using the certificate to get an access token via `AcquireTokenAsync`.

While attempting to write Powershell to make it easier to add certificates to applications, I noticed that you can add an unlimited number of duplicate certificates.  What I mean is that they all have a unique keyId but the same 
`customKeyIdentifier`.  So I wrote the following code to eliminate creating duplicates

```
if ($global:CertificateInfo.Certificate -eq $null)
{
    throw "No certificate has been selected or created yet."
}
$filter = "DisplayName eq '" + $($DisplayName) + "'" ;
$global:CertificateInfo.Application = Get-AzureADApplication -filter $filter


$certificateThumbprint = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String($global:CertificateInfo.Certificate.GetCertHash()) ;
foreach($keyCredential in $global:CertificateInfo.Application.KeyCredentials)
{
    [String]$keyCredentialThumbPrint = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String($keyCredential.CustomkeyIdentifier) ;
    if([String]::Equals($keyCredentialThumbPrint,$certificateThumbprint,[StringComparison]::CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)) {
        throw "This certificate already exists within the keyCredentials collection with KeyId" + "'" + $keyCredential.KeyId + "'" ;
    }
}
```

The code does not work because the `customKeyIdentifier` saved in the application manifest is modified somehow by Azure when it is saved so my duplication check fails.  Does anyone know how Azure is modifying the `customKeyIdentifier` so that I can get my duplicate check to work?

Below is a copy of the duplicates that can show up in your application manifest

```
  "keyCredentials": [
{
  "customKeyIdentifier": "N0l6V0gxM3phNGxvUUk2UnZNdFE0dWV3aDFnPQ==",
  "endDate": "2019-12-18T19:22:10Z",
  "keyId": "6bef2fd1-b163-44fd-8f70-90828a6003ef",
  "startDate": "2017-12-18T23:05:28.4976081Z",
  "type": "AsymmetricX509Cert",
  "usage": "Verify",
  "value": null
},
{
  "customKeyIdentifier": "N0l6V0gxM3phNGxvUUk2UnZNdFE0dWV3aDFnPQ==",
  "endDate": "2019-12-18T19:22:10Z",
  "keyId": "d73d0903-d86f-4277-bbe9-e1cea078b400",
  "startDate": "2017-12-18T21:30:05.8419846Z",
  "type": "AsymmetricX509Cert",
  "usage": "Verify",
  "value": null
}
```

So that people better understand that the issue is in using the New-AzureADApplicationKeyCredential cmdlet and not in the duplicate compare logic I have included the Powershell code I am using below

```
$global:CertificateInfo = @{} ;
function Connect-Azure {
   [CmdletBinding()]
    param
    (
            [parameter(Mandatory=$true)] 
            [string] $TenantId
    )
    Write-Host "Connect-Azure - Enter                                   - $($MyInvocation.MyCommand.Name)"
    Write-Host "Get-ApplicatonKeyCredentials - Parameters"
    Write-Host "                               TenantId                 - $($TenantId)"
    $ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop';

    Connect-AzureAD -TenantId $TenantId
    Write-Host "Connect-Azure - Exit                                    - $($MyInvocation.MyCommand.Name)"
}
function Add-AzureADApplicationKeyCredential { 
   [CmdletBinding()]
    param
    (
            [parameter(Mandatory=$true)] 
            [string] $DisplayName,
            [parameter(Mandatory=$false)] 
            [Switch] $Force
    )
    Write-Host "Add-AzureADApplicationKeyCredential - Enter                    - $($MyInvocation.MyCommand.Name)"
    Write-Host "Add-AzureADApplicationKeyCredential - Parameters"
    Write-Host "                                      DisplayName              - $($DisplayName)"
    $ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop';

    if ($global:CertificateInfo.Certificate -eq $null)
    {
        throw "No certificate has been selected or created yet."
    }
    $filter = "DisplayName eq '" + $($DisplayName) + "'" ;
    $global:CertificateInfo.Application = Get-AzureADApplication -filter $filter


    $certificateThumbprint = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String($global:CertificateInfo.Certificate.GetCertHash()) ;
    foreach($keyCredential in $global:CertificateInfo.Application.KeyCredentials)
    {
        [String]$keyCredentialThumbPrint = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String($keyCredential.CustomkeyIdentifier) ;
        if([String]::Equals($keyCredentialThumbPrint,$certificateThumbprint,[StringComparison]::CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)) {
            throw "This certificate already exists within the keyCredentials collection with KeyId" + "'" + $keyCredential.KeyId + "'" ;
        }
    }


    $CertificateInfo = @{} ;
    $CertificateInfo.CustomKeyIdentifier = [Convert]::ToBase64String($global:CertificateInfo.Certificate.GetCertHash()) ;
    $CertificateInfo.Value = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String($global:CertificateInfo.Certificate.GetRawCertData()) ;
    $CertificateInfo.EndDate = $global:CertificateInfo.Certificate.NotAfter ;
    $CertificateInfo.Type = "AsymmetricX509Cert"
    $CertificateInfo.Usage = "Verify" ;
    $CertificateInfo.ObjectId = $global:CertificateInfo.Application.ObjectId ;

    New-AzureADApplicationKeyCredential @CertificateInfo;


    Write-Host "Add-AzureADApplicationKeyCredential - Exit"     

}
function Select-Certificate {
   [CmdletBinding()]
    param
    (
            [parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
            [string] $CertStoreLocation = "Cert:\LocalMachine\My",
            [parameter(Mandatory=$true)] 
            [string] $ThumbPrint
    )

    Write-Host "Create-SelfSignedCertificate - Enter                    - $($MyInvocation.MyCommand.Name)"
    Write-Host "Get-ApplicatonKeyCredentials - Parameters"    $ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop';
    $certificateLocation = $CertStoreLocation + "\" + $ThumbPrint ;
    $global:CertificateInfo.Certificate = (Get-ChildItem –Path "$($certificateLocation)")
}
function Create-SelfSignedCertificate {
   [CmdletBinding()]
    param
    (
            [parameter(Mandatory=$false)] 
            [string] $Subject, 
            [parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
            [string] $HashAlgorithm = "SHA256",
            [parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
            [string] $CertStoreLocation = "Cert:\LocalMachine\My",
            [parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
            $NotAfter
    )


   ## see https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/scotts-it-blog/2014/12/30/working-with-certificates-in-powershell/
    Write-Host "Create-SelfSignedCertificate - Enter                    - $($MyInvocation.MyCommand.Name)"
    Write-Host "Get-ApplicatonKeyCredentials - Parameters"
    if([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($Subject)) {
        $currentDate = (Get-Date) ;
        $Subject = [String]::Format("SelfSigned{0:yyyymmddHHMMss}",$currentDate) ;
   }
    Write-Host "                               Subject                 - $($Subject)"
    Write-Host "                               HashAlgorithm           - $($HashAlgorithm)"
    Write-Host "                               CertStoreLocation       - $($CertStoreLocation)"
    Write-Host "                               NotAfter                - $($NotAfter)"
    $ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop';

    Write-Host "Create-SelfSignedCertificate - Exit                     - $($MyInvocation.MyCommand.Name)"
    $SaveChooser = New-Object -Typename System.Windows.Forms.SaveFileDialog
    $SaveChooser.CreatePrompt  = $false ;
    $SaveChooser.Title = "Save certficate" ;
    $SaveChooser.DefaultExt = "pfx" ;
    $dialogResult = $SaveChooser.ShowDialog()  
    if($dialogResult -eq [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::Cancel) {        
        return ;
    }

    $CertificatePath = $SaveChooser.Filename ;

    $certificatePassword = Read-host "Please provide a password for the exported certificate."  -AsSecureString 

    $certParameters = @{} ;
    $certParameters.CertStoreLocation = $CertStoreLocation;
    $certParameters.Subject = $Subject;
    $certParameters.KeySpec = "KeyExchange";
    $certParameters.HashAlgorithm = $HashAlgorithm;
    $certParameters.CertStoreLocation = $CertStoreLocation;
    if ($NotAfter -ne $null) {
        $certParameters.NotAfter = $NotAfter;
    }
    $global:CertificateInfo.Certificate = New-SelfSignedCertificate @certParameters ;

    $certificateLocation = $CertStoreLocation + "\" + $global:CertificateInfo.Certificate.Thumbprint ;

    Export-PfxCertificate -Cert $certificateLocation  -FilePath "$($CertificatePath)" -Password $certificatePassword  
}
```

This is how I invoke the code above:

```
Connect-Azure -TenantId "your tenant ID here"
Select-Certificate -ThumbPrint "your thumbprint here"
Add-AzureADApplicationKeyCredential -DisplayName "your-displayname-here"
```

Shown Below are entries in my application manifest the 1st I added manually and the 2nd I added using New-AzureADApplicationKeyCredential cmdlet.  They are the same certificate

```
    {
  "customKeyIdentifier": "7IzWH13za4loQI6RvMtQ4uewh1g=",
  "endDate": "2019-12-15T16:49:37Z",
  "keyId": "fd7be8fc-e44f-4d46-a0e4-fc4ef71b0833",
  "startDate": "2017-12-18T19:12:15Z",
  "type": "AsymmetricX509Cert",
  "usage": "Verify",
  "value": null
},
{
  "customKeyIdentifier": "N0l6V0gxM3phNGxvUUk2UnZNdFE0dWV3aDFnPQ==",
  "endDate": "2019-12-18T19:22:10Z",
  "keyId": "04b0e6a9-bac5-4d3f-be5e-57ddc2976886",
  "startDate": "2017-12-19T15:47:15.9136239Z",
  "type": "AsymmetricX509Cert",
  "usage": "Verify",
  "value": null
},
```

Finally a screen shot from the Keys menu in the app registration

[image]

As you can see the only way to preserve the thumbprint seems to be to NOT use the New-AzureADApplicationKeyCredential cmdlet

Comment: Here is an example of why I want a duplicate check on my certificates

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer.  I used ILSPY to examine the source code and the cmdlet takes the string and converts it into a byte[] using

```
keyCredential.CustomKeyIdentifier = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(this.CustomKeyIdentifier);
```

and while the resulting certificate works the keyCertificateIdentifier is obviously encoded and displayed incorrectly.  BTW I did 3 days of searching and used code from various places on the web and everyone I copied from still had it wrong.

Simple solution was to call cmdlet Set-AzureADApplication rather than cmdlet New-AzureADApplicationKeyCredential.  This requires me to create a Microsoft.Open.AzureAD.Model.KeyCredential in powershell.  Feel free to use the code below

```
    $global:CertificateInfo = @{} ;
function Connect-Azure {
   [CmdletBinding()]
    param
    (
            [parameter(Mandatory=$true)] 
            [string] $TenantId
    )
    Write-Host "Connect-Azure - Enter                                   - $($MyInvocation.MyCommand.Name)"
    Write-Host "Get-ApplicatonKeyCredentials - Parameters"
    Write-Host "                               TenantId                 - $($TenantId)"
    $ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop';

    Connect-AzureAD -TenantId $TenantId
    Write-Host "Connect-Azure - Exit                                    - $($MyInvocation.MyCommand.Name)"
}
function Add-AzureADApplicationKeyCredential { 
   [CmdletBinding()]
    param
    (
            [parameter(Mandatory=$true)] 
            [string] $DisplayName,
            [parameter(Mandatory=$false)] 
            [Switch] $Force
    )
    Write-Host "Add-AzureADApplicationKeyCredential - Enter                    - $($MyInvocation.MyCommand.Name)"
    Write-Host "Add-AzureADApplicationKeyCredential - Parameters"
    Write-Host "                                      DisplayName              - $($DisplayName)"
    $ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop';

    if ($global:CertificateInfo.Certificate -eq $null)
    {
        throw "No certificate has been selected or created yet."
    }
    $filter = "DisplayName eq '" + $($DisplayName) + "'" ;
    $global:CertificateInfo.Application = Get-AzureADApplication -filter $filter


    $certificateThumbprint = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String($global:CertificateInfo.Certificate.GetCertHash()) ;
    foreach($keyCredential in $global:CertificateInfo.Application.KeyCredentials)
    {
        [String]$keyCredentialThumbPrint = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String($keyCredential.CustomkeyIdentifier) ;
        if([String]::Equals($keyCredentialThumbPrint,$certificateThumbprint,[StringComparison]::CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)) {
            throw "This certificate already exists within the keyCredentials collection with KeyId" + "'" + $keyCredential.KeyId + "'" ;
        }
    }

    $keycredential = New-Object Microsoft.Open.AzureAD.Model.KeyCredential
    $keycredential.CustomKeyIdentifier = $global:CertificateInfo.Certificate.GetCertHash() ;
    $keycredential.Value = $global:CertificateInfo.Certificate.GetRawCertData() ;
    $keycredential.EndDate = $global:CertificateInfo.Certificate.NotAfter ;
    $keycredential.StartDate = $global:CertificateInfo.Certificate.NotBefore ;
    $keycredential.Type = "AsymmetricX509Cert"
    $keycredential.Usage = "Verify" ;
    $keycredential.KeyId = [Guid]::NewGuid().ToString() ;
    $global:CertificateInfo.Application.KeyCredentials.Add($keycredential) ;

    Set-AzureADApplication -ObjectID $global:CertificateInfo.Application.ObjectId -KeyCredentials $global:CertificateInfo.Application.KeyCredentials

    Write-Host "Add-AzureADApplicationKeyCredential - Exit"     

}
function Select-Certificate {
   [CmdletBinding()]
    param
    (
            [parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
            [string] $CertStoreLocation = "Cert:\LocalMachine\My",
            [parameter(Mandatory=$true)] 
            [string] $ThumbPrint
    )

    Write-Host "Create-SelfSignedCertificate - Enter                    - $($MyInvocation.MyCommand.Name)"
    Write-Host "Get-ApplicatonKeyCredentials - Parameters"    $ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop';
    $certificateLocation = $CertStoreLocation + "\" + $ThumbPrint ;
    $global:CertificateInfo.Certificate = (Get-ChildItem –Path "$($certificateLocation)")
}
function Create-SelfSignedCertificate {
   [CmdletBinding()]
    param
    (
            [parameter(Mandatory=$false)] 
            [string] $Subject, 
            [parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
            [string] $HashAlgorithm = "SHA256",
            [parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
            [string] $CertStoreLocation = "Cert:\LocalMachine\My",
            [parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
            $NotAfter
    )


   ## see https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/scotts-it-blog/2014/12/30/working-with-certificates-in-powershell/
    Write-Host "Create-SelfSignedCertificate - Enter                    - $($MyInvocation.MyCommand.Name)"
    Write-Host "Get-ApplicatonKeyCredentials - Parameters"
    if([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($Subject)) {
        $currentDate = (Get-Date) ;
        $Subject = [String]::Format("SelfSigned{0:yyyymmddHHMMss}",$currentDate) ;
   }
    Write-Host "                               Subject                 - $($Subject)"
    Write-Host "                               HashAlgorithm           - $($HashAlgorithm)"
    Write-Host "                               CertStoreLocation       - $($CertStoreLocation)"
    Write-Host "                               NotAfter                - $($NotAfter)"
    $ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop';

    Write-Host "Create-SelfSignedCertificate - Exit                     - $($MyInvocation.MyCommand.Name)"
    $SaveChooser = New-Object -Typename System.Windows.Forms.SaveFileDialog
    $SaveChooser.CreatePrompt  = $false ;
    $SaveChooser.Title = "Save certficate" ;
    $SaveChooser.DefaultExt = "pfx" ;
    $dialogResult = $SaveChooser.ShowDialog()  
    if($dialogResult -eq [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::Cancel) {        
        return ;
    }

    $CertificatePath = $SaveChooser.Filename ;

    $certificatePassword = Read-host "Please provide a password for the exported certificate."  -AsSecureString 

    $certParameters = @{} ;
    $certParameters.CertStoreLocation = $CertStoreLocation;
    $certParameters.Subject = $Subject;
    $certParameters.KeySpec = "KeyExchange";
    $certParameters.HashAlgorithm = $HashAlgorithm;
    $certParameters.CertStoreLocation = $CertStoreLocation;
    if ($NotAfter -ne $null) {
        $certParameters.NotAfter = $NotAfter;
    }
    $global:CertificateInfo.Certificate = New-SelfSignedCertificate @certParameters ;

    $certificateLocation = $CertStoreLocation + "\" + $global:CertificateInfo.Certificate.Thumbprint ;

    Export-PfxCertificate -Cert $certificateLocation  -FilePath "$($CertificatePath)" -Password $certificatePassword  
}
```

this results in a manifest that looks like

```
  "keyCredentials": [
{
  "customKeyIdentifier": "KjS6U6xucxo5kuI1YAwykzrmBKE=",
  "endDate": "2019-12-19T19:34:29Z",
  "keyId": "de9bd300-ecdc-43d0-a5a6-e946cce10019",
  "startDate": "2017-12-19T19:24:50Z",
  "type": "AsymmetricX509Cert",
  "usage": "Verify",
  "value": null
 }
],
```

and the display of the keys in the Azure portal looks like this

[image]

the Base64 string in the manifest 'KjS6U6xucxo5kuI1YAwykzrmBKE=' now shows up correctly as the hex representation of the certificate thumbprint '2A34BA53AC6E731A3992E235600C32933AE604A1'.

So in closing:

1. The duplicate check works correctly.
2. The Azure portal correctly shows the thumbprint of the certificate being used.
3. The process is automated to reduce the possibility of cut/paste errors.

Answer (score 0):

> Does anyone know how Azure is modifying the customKeyIdentifier so
>   that I can get my duplicate check to work?

First, you're right. Azure allows you upload one certificates for many times. But each uploading action will get one unique KeyId for the certificate.

I understand what you want to achieve. But My scripts is for find whether the certificate is already uploaded. If you want to  duplicate check on the uploaded  certificates, I think it be better go to Azure portal and find the same certificate quickly, rather than using Powershell. Here is my scripts:

```
    $certs = Get-AzureADApplicationKeyCredential -ObjectId 25f83866-561f-4cf2-b7a6-d623d55864df

    $base64Thumbprint = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String($cer.GetCertHash()) # $cer is your local certificate


    Foreach ($certificate in $certs)
{
        $customkeyIdentifier = $certificate.CustomKeyIdentifier

        $UploadedThumbprint = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String($customkeyidentifier)
        If($UploadedThumbprint -eq $base64Thumbprint)
        {
            Write-Host "This certificate is same as yours and its KeyId is" : $certificate.keyId -ForegroundColor Red
        }

        else
        {
            Write-Host "This certificate is different from your cert and its KeyId is" : $certificate.keyId -ForegroundColor Cyan

        }
}
```

Here is my result:
[image]

Hope this helps!

Comment: I assume that you manually entered your certificates by editing or uploading a new manifest.  If I do that then the customKeyIdentifier is NOT changed and my duplicate check logic works.  However if you add the certificate using the New-AzureADApplicationKeyCredential cmdlet the customKeyIdentifier is modified during the process.